# Google sky alternative

Tags: google-maps

I am looking to develop a commercial game using the sky map (google earth) , from what i understand , google sky can not be used for commercial applications . Is there any alternative ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other free sky projects such as [Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/). Of course, "free" content often comes with its own licensing restrictions.